# Applying Java minor updates

Tags: java, linux-mint, updates, jvm

A bit of a noob question here, but I can't seem to update my Java from 8u31 to 8u45 or 8u51 (Linux Mint 17.2).

I can switch between my Java 7/8/9 easily, but these minor versions are really annoying me, especially when certain programs require 8u45/51 to run because of security issues with 8u31. I downloaded the updates and put them in my /usr/java/ directory, but they don't contain all the files needed to run java, so I have to fall back to the installations in my /usr/lib/jvm/ directory, which contains 8u31. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have problems updating java to a newer version, remove the old version first, then install the newer version. Java is not always succesful in removing the old version first, which is probably the reason you are having this issue.

Comment: Yup! After uninstalling it and reinstalling it, followed by a bit of configuring, it worked! Thanks :)